# login facebook sdk for how long user will be logged in?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

if I use the example from the sdk:
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php

if I press the login button for how long the user be connected?

Comment: u mean the length of user session?

Comment: @azhar I want my users to stay logged in for at least 30 days before they logout(remember me feature) now if someone connect to my site using facebook like in the example for how long he will stay connected without the need to login again

Comment: in above example user is loggedin untill the link logout clicks

Comment: so if i go to the exmaple click log in..  and refresh the page after a  week its will still remember me?

Comment: if ur facebook is loggedin then it will remember you